# How to solve this error "E: Unable to locate package ros-humble-desktop"?

Tags: 22.04, ros

I got this error message while installing ros2 humble on my ubuntu 22.04 . I did follow all off the steps in the ros2 documentation and even tried all over again but still got the same error. Does anyone know how to solve this ?

This error happened when I was trying to install the ros humble deskop on ubuntu 22.04 in my Odroid XU4 by using this command "sudo apt install ros-humble-desktop".

Comment: Have you read this? https://docs.ros.org/en/iron/Installation/Ubuntu-Install-Debians.html

Comment: **Welcome to the Ask Ubuntu community.** Does this resolve/clarify your issue: https://stackoverflow.com/q/72591758/111175?

Answer (score -1):

I have solved this problem

I did this two step

"I am who installed ubuntn in vmware desktop".  first is chaneged my virtual disk folder to not named another langug which not english folder.

second is I've installed ubuntu without option that wifi and some something another option you can toggling anyway. I believe you can understand that

third is Location allowed when installed ubuntu ubuntu.